# How to use isClient in Gridsome?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, dom, gridsome

I am using FirebaseUI with Gridsome plugin and I am getting the error `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. This is due to SSR and FirebaseUI must be calling the window object which is only available on browsers.

I've looked into [Gridsome documentation](https://gridsome.org/docs/client-api/#isclient) and found `process.isClient` should solve the problem but I don't know how I must implement it. Here is the code that I tried:

```js
<script>
import firebase from "@firebase/app";
import * as firebaseui from "firebaseui";
import "firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css";
export default {
  name: "LoginSection",
  mounted() {
    if (process.isClient) {
      this.mountUi();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    mountUi() {
      let ui = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance();
      if (!ui) {
        ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
      }
      const uiConfig = {
        signInSuccessUrl: "/profile",
        signInOptions: [
          firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        ],
      };
      ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try requiring the "firebaseui" package in the isClient statement

```js
<script>
import firebase from "@firebase/app";
import "firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css";
export default {
  name: "LoginSection",
  mounted() {
    if (process.isClient) {
      window.firebaseui = require("firebaseui")
      this.mountUi();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    mountUi() {
      let ui = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance();
      if (!ui) {
        ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
      }
      const uiConfig = {
        signInSuccessUrl: "/profile",
        signInOptions: [
          firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        ],
      };
      ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using a dynamic import in async. Here is my code:

```html
<script>
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css";

export default {
  name: "LoginSection",
  async mounted() {
    const firebaseui = await import("firebaseui");
    let ui = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance();
    if (!ui) {
      ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    }
    const uiConfig = {
      signInSuccessUrl: "/profile",
      signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      ],
    };
    ui.start("#login-section", uiConfig);
  },
};
</script>
```

`require("firebaseui")` would also work, but it's more recommended to use import.